# Copy with planed task, 1ko file

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I've made a Windows batch script to made a backup of a acces database in windows, see the following code

```
set datetimetmp=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%

set datetimetmp=%datetimetmp: =0%

set "filename=ADEL-%datetimetmp%.accdb"

copy G:\ADEL\ADEL_DATA.accdb E:\Library\BACKUP_ADEL\%filename%

echo  >> E:\Library\BACKUP_ADEL\%filename%

set folder=E:\Library\BACKUP_ADEL
set days=3
forfiles /p %folder% /d -%days% /c "cmd /c del @FILE"
@exit
```

This code works very well when I launch it manually, but when the .bat is launch with a windows planned task I have only 1Ko corrupted files in my folder.

Anyone know what happen ?

Comment: The `echo` command is overwriting your file. I can't imagine why it would not do so when you run the batch file manually.

Comment: The Batch run well manually, the Echo edit file to add nothing, I use this to modify the file date.

Comment: Wrong. The `echo` command with no parameters outputs the words "ECHO is on" or "ECHO is off", so it appends this string to your file, thereby corrupting it. This is why the file's modification date changes: it **has** been modified. What you need is a `touch` utility. There are free ones available on the web.

Comment: I found the problem, and actually the "ECHO" with nothing to write can replace the touch utilites, my file is not corrupted.

Comment: @Kromen It's quite possible that Access doesn't care, but you *are* appending "ECHO is on" to the file with that command. The "proper" dirty hack for touching a file is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/07/10/10432879.aspx Another trick to get echo to write an actually empty line is to use `echo.` - but that still outputs an endline, so it will still corrupt your file.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, effectively with this method the file size have lost 1 Ko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I copy the file from the wrong folder, so the 1 Ko files are actually created by the "ECHO" line.